# What is the best way to write log message of my java app into the elk stack?

Tags: logging, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I would like to save the log data from my Java application into an ELK stack. I can configure the format of the log data freely. Unfortunately I can only use log4j 1.x.

What is the easiest way to store log data structured in ELK Stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write text logs structured (today it means Json) and FileBeat delivers them to ES directly (without hassle with Logstash or Fluentd):

```yaml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: filestream
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /app/log/test.log.json
  encoding: utf-8
  prospector.scanner.check_interval: 20s
  prospector.scanner.symlinks: false
  parsers:
    - ndjson:
        keys_under_root: true
  clean_removed: true

# For debugging.
output.console:
  enabled: true
  codec.json:
    pretty: true

output.elasticsearch:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["es1:9200"]
  #protocol: "https"
  #api_key: "id:api_key"
  #username: "elastic"
  #password: "changeme"
  index: "test-%{+yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss}"
```

**PS** I prefer Fluent Bit over FileBeat at the moment. Both can ship events to ES directly without Logstash/Fluentd in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

If you asking for an easy way to ingest your Java app logs into Elasticsearch then install & run `filebeat` to read your app logs and ingest them into ES. You can use filebeat ingest node to be able to parse your logs and store them into individual fields in Elasticsearch to help with visualizing etc. Alternatively, you can also install logstash to do parsing instead of filebeat ingest pipelines. Some links for reading to get you started:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-howto-filebeat.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-ingest-node.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html

Comment: I wonder if it makes sense to write a classic log file and then read it out through filebeat. This approach has the disadvantage that one must explicitly list all used MDC values ​​in the log4j.properties. If you have full control over creating the log file, is not there a better approach? Maybe one of the more dynamic? I always liked the SocketAppender very well, but unfortunately this one is deprecated since ELK 6.x.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your application level logs via `RollingFileAppenders` using Filebeat
Add the below to your `logback.xml` to write app logs to a directory:

```
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/etc/logging/sample.log</file>
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>
                /etc/logging/hsvt_akka.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>5KB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>20</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%date{ISO8601}] [%level] [%logger] [%marker] [%thread] - %msg MDC: {%mdc}%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Now configure filebeat to read these logs written to directory `/etc/logging`, running as a sidecar to your java application in the cluster, for eg k8s

Create configMap for filebeat:

```
filebeat.yml: |
    filebeat:
      inputs:
      - type: filestream
        enabled: true
        paths:
          - /etc/logging/*.log
          - /etc/logging/*.log.*
        prospector:
          scanner:
            check_interval: 1s

      config:
        inputs:
          path: /etc/filebeat.yml
          reload:
            enabled: true
            period: 10s
    output:
      elasticsearch:
        hosts: []
        protocol: 
        username: 
        password:
```

Now add this as a sidecar container to your original java app.

```
- name: filebeat-sidecar
          image: elastic/filebeat:7.16.3
          command: ["filebeat"]
          args: ["-c","/etc/filebeat.yml","-e", "-strict.perms=false"]
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "80Mi"
            requests:
              memory: "60Mi"
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 2000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: filebeat-app-logs
              mountPath: /etc/logging
            - name: filebeat-config
              mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
              subPath: filebeat.yml
      volumes:
        - name: filebeat-app-logs
        - name: filebeat-config
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 0600
            name: filebeat-configmap
            items:
              - key: filebeat.yml
                path: filebeat.yml
```

You need to configure the java app and filebeat to read the same volume where the logs are written to